# Is it necessary to use 'readonly' keyword during service initialization in constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular 2+ combined with Type Script is it necessary to use **readonly** keyword when we initialize services in the component constructor?

What is the purpose to do so?

```
export class MyComponent {

    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

}
```

Comment: the acheive to mark as readonly it's that you can not do this.http="what-ever". Really I don't imagine me writing this instruction, so I never put "readonly"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not necessary to use the **readonly** keyword such usage is not mentioned  in angular docs and not used in practice

Answer (score 3):

It is not required, however it is good practice since you probably don't want to reassign to the `http` property later on.

See the [Typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#read-only-properties-and-index-signatures) for more details:

> Read-only properties may have initializers and may be assigned to in constructors within the same class declaration, but otherwise assignments to read-only properties are disallowed.